# Is is a good practice in DJANGO to create all my project around my User model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-cms

I couldn't find a real andwer for what i need.
I have a king of complex project to build and decided to take the huge task of doing it for the first time while learning django in the proccess (Yes, I know it is not the smartest thing to do, but I think that in the long run it will prove it self...Hope so...LOL)

Any way, In past projects, Using .NET, when designing my DB, I just used followd the UML and made sure that all the rulls are followd. and every thing was OK, as there is not OneToOne corelation between the DB and the project...building the DB i need and then creating the project to talk with with what i need from there....just talking with the right SP....

No, With DJANGO it seem kind of the other way around, and i don't know if the programming model (logic) I used to follow until now is still valid.

And to the point:

I'm building two systems in the same time. The system in general is for a Voluntary rehabilitaion  association. There is the front for the public and users and The CMS/backoffice for the CEO and stuff (many more things then what in the site, but ofcourse, the website gettes the data from the backoffice, like user othentication for login, user name for publictaions and so on...).

So, what I am trying to say, this is kind of User based Project, most the tabels (models?) in one way or the other connect to the user (I wrote models with a questien mark becouse when representing a DB is every thing around the user table, but not sure when changing it to MTV, what really it should look like - becouse of the connection and inheritance and reverse connections between the models)...

I've read all the DJANGOPROJECT docs I could find about it, but as we all know, all the examples over there are very simple, two, three models and i couldn't find a complex example for a project this size....

I would love to do it with django, The learning curve is really really steep, but hopefully, I will open my eyes and world for better things (allready did, and every day i'm falling inlove with it more and more...LONG LIVE OPEN SOURCE (FROM A LONG TIME MICROSOFT JUNKY)...LOL)

Just to show part of the DB tables (as they are in a ms-sql DB, i'm preaty sure it is not the right thing for DJANGO as it doesn't seem logic to me to keep it like that, but for pure SQL this is the way to go): The arrows point to the table where the primary key is in.

> putTypes <- committeePubs -> committees <- committeeMemebers -> Users
>
> ArticleGenres <- ArticleInGenres -> Articles -> Users
>
> ImageTypes <- Images  -> Galleries ->Users
>
> Disabilities <- users

And so on....Every thing is connected to the Users in one way or the othere, wether the User are the primary table or the data provider table....

Now, Can any one help me with this, I know it is a masive request, And ofcourse i am not looking for any one to hold my hand and take me step by step, just looking for a big/comples example so i could learn from there, with a complex set of tables(models) and where and when to build a new app and when to do things in the same app. And also if posible, how to connect the Users table to all the other tables (I know about i import and and just using it, but this is much more complicated then that).

Last thing, Sorry for the grammer mistakes, not my native language...trying to catch them, but I don't always can....

P.S. Another matter, my Users models is much more complicated then the django one, I have many more fields that need to be there, what to do with that?
10x for reading and for helping and any one can....And any way, if not, also 10x :-)

Erez

Comment: I saw that already few people saw my questian, and didn't answer, If there is some thing wrong with it (Too complicated, Not clear, Stupid or any thing else, please let me know so i could modify it or take it off if it is really wrong) and if it is just becouse there were no answer for it, That is fine...Just want to know if the long story is readable and worth the questian...A real open source noobie...It will get better with time from what I know about my self...LOL 10x Again

Comment: I opened the question, read it, saw it was really long, and closed it. Just read it all, and I'm not really sure what you are asking. Try to keep your question text to the bare minimum needed to understand your problem and you may find people more ready to answer.

Comment: 10x Dominic, but i'm having a problem minimizing this question, I had to explain the all thing (as i see it), If I did make it shorter i don't think people would have understand what i need and want. but 10x for the reply...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing particularl wrong with the way you've pictured it there. A couple of points though.

- Django models are usually given singular names - `Committee` rather than `Committees`.
- The `committeeMembers` and `ArticleInGenres` appear to be linking tables in many-to-many relationships. If they're *just* that, and don't store any information of their own other than the two foreign keys, you can leave them out completely - just define a ManyToManyField on `Committee`, pointing at `User`, and Django will create and manage the intermediate table for you.
- The link from `User` to `Disability` is more complicated. You shouldn't really modify the built-in User model. Along with your final point about extra fields on `User`, it seems that your best bet is to define a separate `UserProfile` model with a `OneToOneField` to `User`, on which you can store the extra information.

Comment: Thank you vary much Daniel...great points. The thing is that every table has extra fields in it...that was just the table header. but i read how to add fields to a many to many models. I think i got this part. As for the User, thank you very much. And one last thing, about the apps, I read the DJango manual about the apps, but it is kind of confusing when should i add another app and when to use an existing app. Is articles and app of its own? what about committees? in what app do i put the UserProfile model? how do you decide things like that? 10x again...